# Return a value from a callback within a JSON function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using the iTunes API to gather information. To keep my code modular as far as tasks needed, I have my code setup similar to what's presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143092/getjson-return-data). Adding onto this code I'd like to insert the information from the JSON into the DOM using a click event. The problem is that I'm getting `undefined` whenever the click event is fired despite being able to successfully retrieve the JSON. Why is this so? More importantly is there a better approach to create functions from JSON get requests then what I have now?

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    var artistName = iTunesSearch(albumInfo);
    $(".artist-name").text(artistName);
  });
  
  function iTunesSearch(callback) {
    $.getJSON("http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=College Dropout&entity=album&callback=?", function(data) {
      var result = data['results'][0];
      callback(result);
    });
  }
  
  function albumInfo(data) {
    console.log(data["artistName"]); // Successfully logs info just doesn't return the data 
    return data["artistName"];
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Generate Info</button>
<p><b>Artist Name:</b> <span class="artist-name"></span></p>
```

Comment: Use a callback that does the work to update the DOM. That way, it will run after the asynchronous operation completes.

Comment: So would that require changing `$.getJSON` to `$.ajax`?

Comment: No, the basics are the same with any sort of asynchronous operation. The key is to stop thinking in terms of return values and start using callback functions. You've got a callback already, but it's not taken over all the responsibilities for dealing with the completed lookup operation. That's where the DOM modification should go.